# What does it mean for a fact used in Isabelle to have a number after the name?

Tags: z3, isabelle, smt, hol

Most of the proofs suggested by Sledgehammer use this notation of number inside of parentheses:

```
   by (smt (z3) ApplyAllResult.distinct(1)
            ApplyResult.case(1)
            ApplyResult.case(2)
            ApplyResult.exhaust
            applyInput.simps(1))
```

What does it mean for the fact to have such number?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Isabelle permits the use of *fact lists* indexed by a natural number starting with 1. Given a fact list `fs` and an index `i`, you can access an individual fact from the list by using the syntax `fs(i)`. You can also select multiple facts from the list using multiple indexes (e.g., `fs(1,3)`), ranges (e.g. `fs(2-5)`, `fs(3-)`) or a combination of both (e.g., `fs(2,4-6)`).

Examples of predefined fact lists are `assms` (which contains the assumptions of a theorem) and `f.simps` (which contains the equations defining function `f`).